# How to debugging AngularJS application in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code

I want to debug my AngularJS Application with the Visual Studio Code same like Angular app.

When we create new Angular application we get packages.json and remaining dependencies for run Angular app and its running localhost:4200 port.

Is this possible to same way in AngularJs application using with Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome debugging extension for visual studio code.

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code

Download the extension, setup VS Code to connect to an already running Chrome instance or simply start a new one with remote debugging enabled